# Get resources from dependency

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I want to get some resources from dependency that are not in resources directory, but in src/main/dir.
I tried to use maven-remote-resources-plugin, but I don't know how to change resource directory or even if it's possible.

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>process-remote-resources</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>process</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <resourceBundles>
        <resourceBundle>some:dependency:1.0</resourceBundle>
        </resourceBundles>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/dir</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
         <resource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/dir</directory>
         </resource>
        </resources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I need this resources before generate-sources phase.

Comment: The outputDirectory does not make sense..because it would change your part which is checked into version control system. If you like to use the resources you should simply remove outputDirectory and the `<resources>..</resources>` part..which does not exist...what you can do is to make includes/exludes of parts which should be used and which not...The question is why do you like to use the resources of the given artifact?

Comment: Because I need them to build my project.

Comment: I can't add includes in resourceBundle, because I get error "2nd resource bundle configured must specify a groupId..."